# selenium2 for composer install facing with phalcon/incubator error in PHP

Tags: phalcon

I am using window command prompt,When I update composer facing with below error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject>composer update
Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-
update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubles
hooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
    - Installation request for phalcon/incubator dev-master -> satisfiable by ph
alcon/incubator[dev-master].
    - phalcon/incubator dev-master requires ext-phalcon >=2.0.4 -> the requested
 PHP extension phalcon is missing from your system.
```

Answer (score 1):

The last line should give you a clue: You haven't yet installed PhalconPHP on your system, which is required by the Incubator package.

Also, run a `composer self-update` as recommended.

Comment: I fix environment variable :)